# creating Chart for mvc3 razor using database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, charts

I'm new to asp.net mvc3 and been reading to a lot of posts in stackoverflow on Chart for MVC3 razor.

However, i could not create a chart for this. Basically this is my sql query

```
SELECT COUNT(RequestStatus) AS Expr1, RequestStatus
FROM Request
GROUP BY RequestStatus
```

So far, in my control view, this is my code:

```
public ActionResult RequestReport()
{ 
    var result = from p in db.Requests
                 group p by p.RequestStatus into pgroup
                 let count = pgroup.Count()
                 orderby count
                 select new { Count = count, RequestStatus = pgroup.Key }.ToString();

    var x = new [] {result};    

    Chart chart = new Chart(600, 400)
        .AddSeries(yValues: x , yFields:"Count")
    .AddTitle("Request Statistic");

    this.ViewBag.Chart = chart;      

    return View();
}
```

and
in View :

```
@ViewBag.Chart.Write()
```

please help me solve this issue. i could not find a simple tutorial for this.

ive made some changes on the code in controller.

```
using (var db = new ITAMMVCDBEntities())
            {
                var rs = db.Requests.GroupBy(o=>o.RequestStatus).ToList();
                var result = from o in db.Requests
                             group o by o.RequestStatus
                                 into g
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     result = g.Count()
                                 };

            Chart chart = new Chart(600, 400)
                .AddSeries(
                        xValue: rs.Select(x=>x.Key).ToArray() ,
                        yValues: result.ToArray()
                      )
           .AddTitle("Request Statistic");

            this.ViewBag.Chart = chart;      

            return View();
        }
```

now i get this error msg when run

```
Series data points do not support values of type <>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.Int32] only values of these types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort.
```

i think my xValue is okay as it displays by group 
but problem populationg yValue which will display the value of each group

Comment: Seet this tutorial http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/115/Microsoft-Chart-Controls-to-PDF-with-iTextSharp-and-ASP.NET-MVC

Comment: i managed to solve it... thx guys :)